# Install software using a downloaded port file

Tags: macports

I want to install some software in Mac using 'port install software-name' but some software come with very big package and I don't have a stable connection. I want to download the port file using a download manager and then have port install the software using the downloaded file. Is it possible? How?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For test purposes, I'll use the `octave` port. List the distfiles required for the port by running `port distfiles octave`. You'll get the following output:

```
--->  Distfiles for octave
[octave-3.2.4.tar.gz] /opt/local/var/macports/distfiles/octave/octave-3.2.4.tar.gz
 md5: 90c39fa9e241ad2e978bcee4682a2ba9
 sha1: 93b81fc300bc5e27e88b6668ef0622f29898dfd2
 rmd160: 13b2198db1b8684229d2ba787ebbedd8e50a518c
  http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/pub/mirrors/gnu/ftp/gnu/octave/octave-3.2.4.tar.gz
  http://mirrors.kernel.org/gnu/octave/octave-3.2.4.tar.gz
  http://www.mirrorservice.org/sites/ftp.gnu.org/gnu/octave/octave-3.2.4.tar.gz
  …
  http://lil.fr.distfiles.macports.org/octave/octave-3.2.4.tar.gz
  http://sea.us.distfiles.macports.org/macports/mpdistfiles/octave/octave-3.2.4.tar.gz
  http://svn.macports.org/repository/macports/distfiles/octave/octave-3.2.4.tar.gz
```

Inside the square brackets is the name of the file to download, followed by the path that MacPorts will search for the file. The links below that are a number of mirrors you could download from using your download manager. Go to `/opt/local/var/macports/distfiles` and create a directory called `octave` if it doesn't exist. Put the downloaded source package in that folder. Proceed to install using `sudo port install octave`.

Make sure that you have all the distfiles belonging to a given port as many ports have more than one.

Comment: Use [this Hint](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4755274/downloading-macports-dependencies-without-installing) to download All Dependencies for a port before installing.

Answer (score 6):

This didn't quite work for me. The `port distfiles ntfs-3g` gives me

```
--->  Distfiles for ntfs-3g
[ntfs-3g_ntfsprogs-2012.1.15.tgz] /opt/local/var/macports/distfiles/ntfs-3g/ntfs-3g_ntfsprogs-2012.1.15.tgz
md5: 341acae00a290cab9b00464db65015cc
sha1: 8d55cf49afde172fefa369a0a85289e09c4d7bbb
rmd160: 4db6ea1025eedeee160a1cd4238d069a307b9b35
  http://tuxera.com/opensource/ntfs-3g_ntfsprogs-2012.1.15.tgz
  http://distfiles.macports.org/ntfs-3g/ntfs-3g_ntfsprogs-2012.1.15.tgz
  http://aarnet.au.distfiles.macports.org/pub/macports/mpdistfiles/ntfs-3g/ntfs-3g_ntfsprogs-2012.1.15.tgz
  http://cjj.kr.distfiles.macports.org/ntfs-3g/ntfs-3g_ntfsprogs-2012.1.15.tgz
  http://fco.it.distfiles.macports.org/mirrors/macports-distfiles/ntfs-3g/ntfs-3g_ntfsprogs-2012.1.15.tgz
  http://her.gr.distfiles.macports.org/mirrors/macports/mpdistfiles/ntfs-3g/ntfs-3g_ntfsprogs-2012.1.15.tgz
  http://jog.id.distfiles.macports.org/macports/mpdistfiles/ntfs-3g/ntfs-3g_ntfsprogs-2012.1.15.tgz
  http://lil.fr.distfiles.macports.org/ntfs-3g/ntfs-3g_ntfsprogs-2012.1.15.tgz
  http://mse.uk.distfiles.macports.org/sites/distfiles.macports.org/ntfs-3g/ntfs-3g_ntfsprogs-2012.1.15.tgz
  http://ykf.ca.distfiles.macports.org/MacPorts/mpdistfiles/ntfs-3g/ntfs-3g_ntfsprogs-2012.1.15.tgz
  http://svn.macports.org/repository/macports/distfiles/ntfs-3g/ntfs-3g_ntfsprogs-2012.1.15.tgz
```

but when I execute `sudo port install ntfs-3g` it says

```
--->  Attempting to fetch ntfs-3g-2012.1.15_3.darwin_11.x86_64.tbz2 from http://packages.macports.org/ntfs-3g
```

To achieve the same result, I downloaded `http://packages.macports.org/ntfs-3g/ntfs-3g-2012.1.15_3.darwin_11.x86_64.tbz2` and put it in `/opt/local/var/macports/incoming/verified`. `sudo port install ntfs-3g` then finds the file i have downloaded and does not try to download it again. I found the same with the `llvm-3.1` package.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
port rdeps "portname"
```

where "portname" is the name of the port. Go to the following link for more info:

https://trac.macports.org/wiki/FAQ

Comment: According to the FAQ you linked, `rdep` lists package dependencies, not files to download.